Murata MLCC GRM series capacitors - DigiKey shows "Not For New Designs" - but Murata introduces GRM series as "New". Some error?
Murata MLCC GRM series capacitors

DigiKey shows "Not For New Designs", PN: GRM1885C1H331JA01D
but Murata introduces GRM series as "New".

Is it some kind of error?

If you lookup the exact partnumber on Muratas website it will show up as NRFD.


It's oddly written (and perhaps this is an artifact of translation), but I think what they mean is:

Through [Murata's] latest multi-layer ceramic capacitor (MLCC) introduction,


[in] the GRM series of MLCCs


[with] capacitance values of 10µF (and a ±20% tolerance)


supplied in a 0201inch/0603M package size

i.e. the following clauses/sentences are descriptive, adding onto and specifying the overall subject matter of the paragraph.
Analogously, when "introducing a tasty new apple", we understand that apples already exist, independent of any varieties thereof, so it's not that apples in general have been introduced, but a new variety.  But here, not necessarily being aware of what a "GRM" is, a reader might well infer that it is (or at least in part) what has been introduced.  You are correct, in that the phrasing isn't great, or is ambiguous, or written in an unfamiliar style.
The GRM line is vast, and, I don't know that it's really a type-family as such, but you'd have to ask them what categorizes or differentiates it; to my understanding, it's just the general-purpose set of products, which may (despite that generality) have some specialization or innovation between them, but that aren't different or special enough to categorize elsewhere.  Likewise, parts come and go; it's not the series that's going NRND, but individual types (or sets thereof) within it.

Some 5 years back, there were rumours that Murata were about to cancel all production of ceramic capacitors larger than 0402. They did put a whole lot of parts as NRND/EOL at the time.
Which in turn caused panic with people starting to hoard cermaic caps and prices skyrocketing. I don't think they have yet to actually cancel all production though, if that was even the plan in the first place or just a rumour. They seem to repeatedly cancel parts that aren't profitable for them.
Here's the backstory:
Murata: Ceramic capacitor lead times continue to stretch; parts go EOL. Since then prices and availability have stabilized.

I personally don't quite trust Murata since then though, and I tend to specify competing brands as 1st source these days. Overall, Murata has a tendency to often EOL all manner components and not just ceramic caps, making them an untrustworthy supplier to avoid for production purposes.
